# Install raspell gem on Heroku using Vulcan

Tags: heroku, rubygems, aspell

I would like to use the [thinking-sphinx-raspell](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx-raspell/) gem to allow did-you-mean suggestions for searches on our website. It works on my development machine (Mountain Lion), but I'm having difficulty deploying it on Heroku Cedar.

The gem depends on the [raspell](https://github.com/evan/raspell) gem which in turn depends on [aspell](http://aspell.net/). Because aspell is not included in the Heroku Cedar stack, I'm using Vulcan to compile it on an Heroku machine, add the binary to my git repository and then push that to Heroku. I described the steps in more detail [here](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx-raspell/issues/11#issuecomment-11874991).

This results in an error during the bundler phase:

```
Installing raspell (1.3)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for aspell.h... no
checking for main() in -laspell... no
creating Makefile
make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RUBY_H -I/opt/local/include    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -o raspell.o -c raspell.c
In file included from raspell.c:2:
raspell.h:6:20: error: aspell.h: No such file or directory
```

If I understand correctly, this dependency on aspell.h is set in [extconf.rb](https://github.com/evan/raspell/blob/master/ext/extconf.rb) of the raspell gem:

```
have_header("aspell.h")
```

I put that header file in my project's bin directory. Not the best place, but I don't think that's the problem. This corresponds to `/app/bin` on the Heroku file system. I added this path to `PATH`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and also set `CFLAGS` to `-I/app/bin`.

What I am doing wrong? Or am I trying something that's just not going to work on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Heroku's buildpacks?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

They seem like a way to customize the stack. (They might have been introduced since you asked your question.)